# Return a yes or no if a value is matched on another column on a different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel workbook with 2 sheets. One sheet is called Roster and sheet 2 is called Safety Meeting. On sheet 2(Safety Meeting) is a column with [Id#-name] for those who attended. How do I get “Yes” or “No”return on sheet 1(Roster) for those who attended on sheet 2(Safety Meeting). Also, Roster sheet only has ID# and on Safety Meeting sheet it has ID#andName, but I only need to match the ID number.
I was trying IF and MATCH functions, but having a column with ID numbers and name is throwing me off.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's always good if you're able to provide a [mcve] with dummy data if necessary, so folk can see exactly what it is you're trying to do and exactly what you've tried. Harder to do with spreadsheets than with code, of course.

Answer (score 0):

So something like:

```
if(iferror(match(id_num,range_safety_meeting,0),0)>0,"Yes","No")
```

As you don't show what any of the data looks like I have just shown the structure.

Match has two compulsory arguments, while the third is optional, however I always set 0 for an exact match or 1 for a descending or -1 for an ascending result.

Comment: You might prefer `XMATCH(key,range)` to `MATCH(key,range,0)`

Comment: @JackDeeth but MATCH() works in more versions of Excel than XMATCH(), some on here have older versions of Excel and the OP does actually Tag Excel-2010...

Comment: @JackDeeth XMATCH() also has the 3rd argument as match_mode and the 4th argument as search_mode so not sure where the advantage comes?

Comment: I missed the Excel-2010 tag. Good shout. I prefer XMATCH when able because `,0` is confusing to any colleague not intimately familiar with MATCH.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you have a sheet called `Roster`, and a sheet called `Safety Meeting`, and in the second sheet you have a column with ID and name, separated with a hyphen?

###### Option 1: the `Roster` sheet has the same names as the `Safety Meeting` sheet

1. Combine the ID and name on the Roster sheet in the same format as in `Safety Meeting`:

```
=A:A  & "-" & B:B        for Excel 2010
=@A:A & "-" & @B:B       for current version
Gives e.g. "24601-Valjean"
```

2. `MATCH` this combined ID-name in the `Safety Meeting` column. I have named that column `attendees`

```
=MATCH(  A:A & "-" &  B:B, attendees, 0)    Excel 2010
=XMATCH(@A:A & "-" & @B:B, attendees)       Current
Gives row number if found or #N/A if not found
```

3. Convert to `TRUE`/`FALSE`

```
=NOT( ISNA( MATCH( A:A & "-" &  B:B, attendees, 0)))      Excel 2010
=NOT( ISNA( MATCH(@A:A & "-" & @B:B, attendees, 0)))      Current
```

[image: Screenshot demonstrating above outcome]

###### Option 2: the `Roster` sheet does not have exactly the same names as `Safety Meeting`

1. Choose a helper column for the `Safety Meeting` attendees. This could be on the same sheet, or on a hidden sheet. I have named it `attendee_id`
2. Find the `-` in `attendees`:

```
=FIND("-",  attendees)    Excel 2010
=FIND("-", @attendees)    Current
```

[image: screenshot of above]

3. Get the first (that-many minus one) characters from `attendees` - this is the ID:

```
=LEFT( attendees, FIND("-",  attendees) - 1 )     Excel 2010
=LEFT(@attendees, FIND("-", @attendees) - 1 )     Current
```

4. Look up `Roster` IDs in this helper column:

```
"At meeting?" column
=NOT( ISNA( MATCH( A:A, attendee_id, 0)))    Excel 2010
=NOT( ISNA( MATCH(@A:A, attendee_id, 0)))    Current
```

5. Observe this didn't work:
   [image: 24601 isn't matched despite being in roster.id and attendees_id]
6. The `Roster` IDs have numeric values, while `attendee_id` has text value. They must be made to match. Replace `A:A` with `TEXT(A:A,0)` to format the number as text.

```
=NOT( ISNA( MATCH( TEXT( A:A, 0), attendee_id, 0)))   Excel 2010
=NOT( ISNA( MATCH( TEXT(@A:A, 0), attendee_id, 0)))   Current
```

[image: Screenshot of above]

Comment: Option 1 is what I was describing, thank you. How would I have it return a YES or NO, instead of True/False?

Comment: Sure - you can probably format `TRUE`/`FALSE` to be Yes/No, but you can encode it as text: `=IF(<some expression>,"Yes","No")`

Comment: Appreciate the help boss. First Time here and surprised with the quick responses.

Comment: The benefit/curse of solving this exact problem, or others very much like it, more times than I can count over the last 20-odd years ;)