# If ID number matches it will return a yes, or will return a "NO" if NO ID number was found to match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel workbook with 2 sheets. One sheet is called Roster and sheet 2 is called Safety Meeting. On sheet 2(Safety Meeting) is a column with [Id#-name] for those who attended. How do I get “Yes” or “No” return on sheet 1(Roster) on  Column C, for those who attended on sheet 2(Safety Meeting). Also, Roster sheet only has ID# and on Safety Meeting sheet it has ID#andName, but I only need to match the ID number. And if ID# is not there it returns a "NO" because there is no match or its missing.
**Note: Im only trying to match ID#s, so Column A on Roster Sheet and Column B on Safety Meeting sheet. Sometimes on Column B of Safety Sheet it will only show "ID#- "(ex. 900003- ). Thats why the ID#s only matters not name**
I was trying IF and MATCH functions, but having a column with ID numbers and name is throwing me off.
[Roster Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94QJ5.png)
[Safety Meeting attendees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz74e.png)

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2&"*",'Safety Meeting'!B:B,0)),"Yes","No")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return a yes or no if a value is matched on another column on a different sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71064916/return-a-yes-or-no-if-a-value-is-matched-on-another-column-on-a-different-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may try using in this was as well,

Formula used in cell C2

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,--LEFT($G$2:$G$7,FIND("-",$G$2:$G$7)-1),0)),"No","Yes")
```

And Fill Down!

With respect to your workbook the formula should be like this in cell **C2 - ROSTER SHEET**

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,--LEFT('Safety Meeting'!$B$2:$B$7,FIND("-",'Safety Meeting'!$B$2:$B$7)-1),0)),"No","Yes")
```

Please adjust the ranges accordingly as per your data, !

[image: ID number matches]